# Google webtools: Fetch and Render shows blank page

Tags: angularjs, indexing, web-crawler, googlebot, google-crawlers

[Website](http://www.tapdiscover.com/) is made using AngularJS with Nginx. The partial status in fetch and render is due to fetching user info without authentication which is fine.

GoogleBot renders a perfect blank page on doing Fetch and Render. The site is rendering fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. There must be some errors when GoogleBot renders page. **Where can I find the log of the errors?** Or something like developers console does exist for GoogleBot too?

Comment: I used the window.onerror handler to get the error information. You can find more details in [this blog post](https://blog.codaxy.com/debugging-googlebot-crawl-errors-for-javascript-applications-5d9134c06ee7#.kojxdsnyd) where I wrote about my experience.